# iOS Update UIImage with other UIImage after allocating

Tags: ios, objective-c, video, uiimage

Ok the case might sound simple, but i can't figure out how to do this:

```
        //
        CGImageRef ImagRef      = [self imageFromSampleBuffer:sampleBuffer];

        // Allocate m_pIMAGE at the first frame
        if(m_pIMAGE == NULL)
        {
            m_pIMAGE = [[UIImage alloc] initWithCGImage:(ImagRef)];
        }
        else
        {
            // Copy the frame image (ImagRef) into the m_pIMAGE

        }


        CGImageRelease( ImagRef );
```

How do i update my m_pIMAGE with ImageRef after it was allocated at the first frame?

Comment: You can't. Just re-init it.

Comment: You can release m_pIMAGE reference and reallocate. Something like this `if(m_pIMAGE){[m_pIMAGE release]; m_pIMAGE=nil;}` then reallocate `m_pIMAGE = [[UIImage alloc] initWithCGImage:(ImagRef)];`

Comment: Huh, what a pitty! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Image should be assigned in main thread...

```
CGImageRef ImagRef = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(context);


CFRetain(ImagRef);
// Create an image object from the Quartz image
if([NSThread isMainThread]) {
    if(m_pIMAGE == NULL) {
        m_pIMAGE = [[UIImage alloc] initWithCGImage:(ImagRef)];
    } else {
    }
    CFRelease(ImagRef);
} else {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        if(m_pIMAGE == NULL) {
            m_pIMAGE = [[UIImage alloc] initWithCGImage:(ImagRef)];
        } else {
        }
        CFRelease(ImagRef);
    }); 
}
// Release the Quartz image
CGImageRelease(ImagRef);
```

Answer (score 2):

Using ARC ,just reinitialize it ,otherwise.Release and set the pointer to nil.then reallocate